How embedded tomcat works?
Just wanted to know in detail. How embedded tomcat works in springboot application ?. How it executes the appplication jar. please share the link to study about springboot embedded server.
I tried running sringboot application. But how embedded tomcat jar executes runs our application

Spring Boot uses an embedded servlet container approach, which means that it packages the servlet container (like Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow) as a JAR dependency and runs the application as a standalone application. This is different from traditional Java web applications which are packaged as WAR files and deployed on a standalone servlet container or application server.
Here's a simplified explanation of how Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat works:

When a Spring Boot application starts, it creates an instance of SpringApplication which is responsible for running the application.

SpringApplication then initializes the Spring context. The Spring context is responsible for creating and managing beans defined in the application.

As part of the context initialization, Spring Boot auto-configuration kicks in. This is where Spring Boot's "convention over configuration" philosophy comes into play. Spring Boot auto-configuration is a feature which allows automatic configuration of Spring application based on the JAR dependencies that you added in the project.

If Spring Boot detects that Tomcat is on the classpath and that no other web server is configured, it auto-configures an embedded Tomcat instance. This is done by the TomcatServletWebServerFactory which is responsible for configuring and initializing an instance of Tomcat.

The TomcatServletWebServerFactory creates an instance of Tomcat and configures it. It sets up the HTTP connector, initializes the context, and sets up any necessary Tomcat lifecycle listeners.

Once the Tomcat instance is set up, Spring Boot starts it. Tomcat then listens for HTTP requests on the configured port and forwards those requests to the appropriate Spring controllers for processing.

When the application is shut down, Spring Boot stops the embedded Tomcat server.


This approach simplifies deployment and distribution of the application, as you only need a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) to run the application and there's no need to install and maintain a separate servlet container or application server.
Reference: https://medium.com/javarevisited/what-happens-internally-when-you-start-a-spring-boot-application-part1-a683a64c1be8
